# Jquery field clearing issue

Tags: jquery, html

You can see the below snippet is written to prevent characters and allow only numbers.It gets into the if condition but the field is not cleared.

```js
$(document).on('keyup', '.childfield', function(e) {

  if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
    //display error message
    console.log("Entered");
    return false;

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="childfield" value="0">
```

Hope Someone can find what i am doing wrong.

Comment: you can use `keydown` instead, the character is already entered into the input field when the key is released

Comment: @NickParsons Yaa that seems fine but i need to write an ajax call using the field value on the else condition

Comment: The event you use isn't related to that

Comment: You can use the `input` event on input type number or on input with a pattern attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code for Numeric values only

```js
$(document).on('keyup', '.childfield', function(e) {

  if (/\D/g.test(this.value))
  {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="childfield" value="0">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a useful way, that can handle pasting too

You should not ajax immediately. Either debounce or wait for enter

```js
const re = /[^0-9a-zA-Z]+/g
$(document).on('input', '.childfield', function(e) {
  let val = this.value;
  if (re.test(val)) {
    console.log("invalid input")
    this.value=val.replace(re,"")
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="childfield" value="0">
```

Submitting on enter

```js
const re = /[^0-9a-zA-Z]+/g
$(function() {
  $(document).on('input', '.childfield', function(e) { 
    let val = this.value;
    if (re.test(val)) {
      console.log("invalid input")
      this.value = val.replace(re, "")
    }
  });
  $("#form1").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop submitting
    if (re.test($("#form1 .childField").val())) { // not even possible but still
      return;
    }
    // $.ajax()... // here you can send
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1">
  <input type="text" class="childfield" value="0" />
</form>
```